# How to select a tests form a test suite

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, test-suite, test-plan

I have a stage with the follow tasks:
[image]

There are 2 test suites with 8 test cases.
I want to execute only test cases with tag "download" in feature file
[image]

When I locally execute command

```
dotnet test <name>.dll --filter TestCategory=download
```

everything is fine, but when I try to add command-line options in "Other console options" in task
[image]
test cases are not filtered and all are executed.

What am I doing wrong and what can help me to filter tests?

Answer (score 1):

The other console options are not honored when running from a test plan.  You either need to change it to select tests using an assembly (which matches your local copy) or you need to filter the tests in the suite using a filter criteria not tied in source code.

If you expand the info of that option:

> These options are not supported and will be ignored when running tests
> using the ‘Multi agent’ parallel setting of an agent job **or when
> running tests using ‘Test plan’ option.** The options can be specified
> using a settings file instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Matt! Can you tell me how not to use a settings file in this case? (the project created with .NET Core 3.1)

Comment: I don't think TestCaseFilter is one of the properties allowed in the runsettings file.  You would probably need to either filter your suite or run against the specific assembly instead.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2019&redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 1):

Matt is correct. The `other console options` in Visual Studio test task doesn't support running from a test plan.

To solve this issue, you could use `.runsettings` file.

Now, versions after VS 16.6 preview 3 can support adding `testcasefilter` to .runsettings  directly.

Here is an example:

.runsettings file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <!-- Configurations that affect the Test Framework -->
  <RunConfiguration>
    <MaxCpuCount>1</MaxCpuCount>
    <!-- Path relative to directory that contains .runsettings file-->
    <ResultsDirectory>.\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>
    <TestCaseFilter>TestCategory=xxx</TestCaseFilter>
  </RunConfiguration>
....
```

Pipeline Settings:

[image]

You could install the `VS 16.7.1` in `Visual Studio Test Platform Installer` task.

Then you could set the Test Platform version and runsettings file in the visual studio test task.

[image]

Here is a ticket about [testcasefilter in runsettings file](https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/pull/2356).